# Having problems with writeFile in Haskell IO

Tags: file, haskell, io

First of all im new around here and thanks for helping out.

The problem is basically i am being unable to write into a file by using writeFile in Haskell.
Code:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Input file: "
    ifile <- getLine
    result <- readFile ifile >>= print . emit . compile . calc . lexer
    print result
```

This is what i currently have and i know that the function `emit` is returning correctly.
Aditional info on functions im using:

```
    emit :: (Int, Int, [Stuff]) -> String
    compile :: C -> (Int, Int, [Stuff])
```

I can get the result printed with the above code and it returns along lines of:

```
"stuff i want"
()
```

I'm finding the `()` funny but i figure i can remove it from the file afterwards.

When i try to use the writeFile in the following manner:

```
writeFile "file.txt" results
```

It gives me the following error:

```
    Couldn't match type `()' with `[Char]'
    Expected type: String
      Actual type: ()
    In the second argument of `writeFile', namely `result'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: writeFile "result.txt" result
    In the expression:
      do { putStrLn "Input file: ";
        ifile <- getLine;
        result <- readFile ifile >>= print . emit . compile . calc . lexer;
        writeFile "result.txt" result }
```

Anyone knows how i can fix this? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "funny" `()` is actually the key to understanding this. The output `()` is emitted by the last line of `main`, `print result`, because `result` has type `()`.

Why? Because it is bound to the result of `print . emit . compile . calc . lexer =<< readFile ifile`; or, simplified, to the result of `print . f =<< readFile ifile` for some pure compiler pipeline `f`. The result of this is the result of the `print`, which is just `()` (`print` doesn't return anything useful, it just prints its argument to stdout as an effect).

What you want to do is to not `print` anything then and there, and just bind the actual result of running your compile pipeline; i.e. something like

```
result <- emit . compile . calc . lexer <$> readFile ifile
```